# UIScreen class is gone in ios10 simulator sdk

Tags: ios, simulator, ios10, uiscreen, mainscreen

I used

> [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width

code before ios10.
But when I build this code using ios10 simulator sdk, it occurs error like

> "Receiver 'UIScreen' for class message is a forward declaration No
>   known class method for selector 'mainScreen'".

And I know the **UIScreen** class is not existed in ios10 simulator sdk not ios10 sdk.

first, Is it different *built in ios10 sdk* with *ios10 simulator*??
and second, How can I handle this compile error.

Comment: It compiled well with ios10 sdk which is contained Xcode. only not complied in ios10 simulator sdk.

Comment: Did you import UIKit?

Comment: Sorry.. It is solved after reinstall Xcode,..